# trying to do concatenate in a program but isnt printing

Tags: java

my program is to to read a file that contains two languages, suppose they are A and B, and then implement the following three operations:

```
• A ∪ B = {x | x ∈ A or x ∈ B}. 
• A ◦ B = {xy | x ∈ A and y ∈ B}. 
• Aᵏ = {x₁x₂ . . . xk | k ≥ 0 and each xi ∈ A}, where k is a natural number from keyboard.
```

i have gotten the union and the power rules to perform what they need to do and print it out but my concatenate is not working or printing out for some reason. Am i missing something in my code?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class proj1
{
   public static void main(String[]Args){
       //read from file
       List<String> setsUnion = readSetFromFile("Pro-1_Example.txt");
       // splits the sets in the file
       List<String> setA = new ArrayList<>();
       List<String> setB = new ArrayList<>();
       boolean readingA = true;
       for(String line:setsUnion){
        if(line.equals("")){
            readingA = false;
        } else{
            if(readingA){
                setA.add(line);
            }else{
                setB.add(line);
            }
        }
        }
       // getting user input for the variable k
       int k = getUserInput();
       // set operation
       List<String> unionSet = union(setA,setB);
       List<String> concatSet = concatenate(setA,setB);
       List<String> powerSet = power(setA, k);
       // Print the results
        System.out.println("A ∪ B = " + unionSet);
        System.out.println("A ◦ B = " + concatSet);
        System.out.println("A^" + k + " = " + powerSet);
   }
    // Get user input for the exponent k
    private static int getUserInput() {
        int k = 0;
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print("Enter the exponent k: ");
            k = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return k;
    }
  // read from a file and return as a List
  private static List<String> readSetFromFile(String fileName) {
    List<String> s = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.trim();
            if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                s.add(line);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return s;
   } 
    // Perform set power operation
    private static List<String> power(List<String> set, int k) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add("");
        // Iterate from 1 to k to generate combinations
        for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
            List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            // Generate combinations for the current exponent
            for (String e : set) {
                for (String abc : result) {
                    temp.add(abc + e);
                }
            }
            result.addAll(temp);
        }
        return result;
    }
   // Perform set union
   private static List<String> union(List<String> setA, List<String> setB) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(setA);
    for (String element : setB) {
        if (!result.contains(element)) {
            result.add(element);
        }
    }
    return result;
   } 
   // Perform set concatenation
    private static List<String> concatenate(List<String> setA, List<String> setB) {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String a : setA) {
            for (String b : setB) {
                results.add(a + b);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

ive tried rewriting it a couple different ways hoping to get it to print the result but im getting nothing

Comment: In your function `readSetFromFile()` you only add a line to the list if it is not empty. In your `main()`function you switch from reading setA to reading setB when you encounter an empty line. I guess that setB will remain empty. Therefore there's nothing to concatenate

Comment: This is almost definitely more code than you need in order to reproduce whatever problem you're having. You should take the time to whittle it down to just the few lines that reproduce the problem: this is often 10 lines or fewer. This makes it much easier for us to answer the question. In the process, you may even find you figure out the solution yourself.

Comment: (for example, if the problem isn't in generating the `List<String>`s, you can just hard-code them for purpose of this question)

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Path file = Paths.get("Pro-1_Example.txt");
        // using NIO to easily read all lines from the text file
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file);

        // using special collection for unique ordered elements
        Set<String> setA = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        Set<String> setB = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        splitLines(lines, setA, setB);

        // using Scanner for user input
        System.out.print("Enter the exponent k: ");
        int k = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("A ∪ B = " + union(setA, setB));
        System.out.println("A ◦ B = " + concat(setA, setB));
        System.out.format("A^%s = %s\n", k, power(setA, k));
    }

    private static void splitLines(List<String> lines, Set<String> setA, Set<String> setB) {
        boolean readA = true;

        for (String line : lines) {
            if (line.isEmpty())
                readA = false;
            else if (readA)
                setA.add(line);
            else
                setB.add(line);
        }
    }

    // use Set to keep elements unique
    private static Set<String> union(Set<String> setA, Set<String> setB) {
        Set<String> res = new LinkedHashSet<>(setA);
        res.addAll(setB);
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(res);
    }

    private static Set<String> concat(Set<String> setA, Set<String> setB) {
        Set<String> res = new LinkedHashSet<>();

        for (String a : setA)
            for (String b : setB)
                res.add(a + b);

        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(res);
    }

    private static Set<String> power(Set<String> set, int k) {
        Set<String> res = new LinkedHashSet<>(set);

        for (int i = 1; i < k; i++) {
            List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>();

            for (String e : set)
                for (String abc : res)
                    tmp.add(abc + e);

            res.addAll(tmp);
        }

        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(res);
    }

}
```

---

**Demo**
`Pro-1_Example.txt`

```
a
b
c
d
e

1
2
3
4
5
```

Then output is:

```
Enter the exponent k: 2
A ∪ B = [a, b, c, d, e, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
A ◦ B = [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, e1, e2, e3, e4, e5]
A^2 = [a, b, c, d, e, aa, ba, ca, da, ea, ab, bb, cb, db, eb, ac, bc, cc, dc, ec, ad, bd, cd, dd, ed, ae, be, ce, de, ee]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.